# C# List duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, duplicates

I am wondering why when I try to not add my object in the list when it's duplicate it's still adding it

```
if (thePreviousList.Contains(thePreviousItem))
{
}
else
{
    thePreviousList.Add(thePreviousItem);
}
```

For example thepreviousitem id = 1 and name = test 
And if i have another object with the same id and same name it will still add it...

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` instead of list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to override Equals, you can use LINQ to check if an object with the same ID and name (which is not necessarily *the same object*) already exists:

```
if (thePreviousList.Any(item => item.ID == thePreviousItem.ID
                             && item.Name == thePreviousItem.Name)) 
{ 
} 
else 
{ 
    thePreviousList.Add(thePreviousItem); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to properly implement `Equals` method on the object you are trying to add to the list. To determine whether the list already contains the passed object, `Contains` method is using `Equals`.

Comment: What can I do then to do not add the object in the list if there is a duplicate ? Without using equals method ?

Comment: Why would you not want to use `Equals` method? It's the simplest thing to do.

Comment: @Emged You can either use a collection that won't accept duplicates (i.e. a set, such as HashSet<T>) and provide a comparator, or you can write your own Contains method that searches the list looking for the item using a custom comparer.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

> This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable(Of T).Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).

If you haven't implemented `IEquatable<T>.Equals`, it's using the default which is reference equality. Alternatively, you implemeted `IEquatable<T>.Equals` but didn't do it properly.

> For example thepreviousitem id = 1 and name = test And if i have another object with the same id and same name it will still add it...

You need something like

```
class Foo : IEquatable<Foo> {
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Foo(int id, string name) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public bool Equals(Foo other) {
        return this.Id == other.Id && this.Name == other.Name;
    }
}
```

Finally, if checking for duplicates is something you're going to be doing a lot of, then you shouldn't use `List<T>`. You should use `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to implement `IEquatable<T>`, overriding `Equals` is enough, since the default comparer will call `Equals` if `IEquatable<>` is not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds from your comments on other answers that you don't want to override `Equals`.

You can instead do this:

```
if (thePreviousList.Any(item => thePreviousItem.id == item.id && thePreviousItem.name == item.name))
{

}
else
{
    thePreviousList.Add(thePreviousItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `List<>.Contains` is checking for *references* not checking the properties of objects in the list.

For this to work you should override `Equals`, and for best practice override `GetHashCode` too. The rule should be that when `Equals` returns true, the same hash code should be returned.

Something like the following for you should suffice:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   var i = obj as YourType;
   if(i == null) return false;

   return i.Id == this.Id && i.Name == this.Name;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
   return this.Id.GetHashCode() ^ this.Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: What can I do then to do not add the object in the list if there is a duplicate ?

Comment: @Emged - See update (Although I see your comment below about not using Equals - this always baffles me... why would you want to do something any way other than the *right* way?)